Does esbuild support to bundle files for express.static
I have an express project which use express.static to serve front-UI files.
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

The front-UI is an Angular project, after building, it generate below files:

favicon.ico
index.html
main.js
polyfills.js
styles.css

Below is my esbuild bundle command used:
"scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app.js --bundle --external:./public/* --platform=node --outfile=out.js"
  },

When run build command, the files(html, css, js, ico) under public folder is not bundled into out.js. Express still use the files under public folder.
My question is: Can esbuild bundle the files under public folder, so I can continue to use express.static?
